# exclude dropped values iteratively

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of x,y,z data like such:

```
x  y  z
1  1  0
1  1  2
1  1  3
1  2  1
2  1  3
2  2  3
2  2  4
```

I want to select the duplicates and drop them (by column x and y), like such:

Not duplicates:

```
x  y  z
1  1  0
1  2  1
2  1  3
2  2  3
```

Duplicates:

```
x  y  z
1  1  2
1  1  3
2  2  4
```

And then I want to do it again (recursively):

Not duplicates:

```
x  y  z
1  1  2
2  2  4
```

Duplicates

```
x  y  z
1  1  3
```

How would one accomplish (the exclusion of subsets until no subset is left)?
I currently have this:

```
notDuplicate = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x', 'y'], keep='first')
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the pandas function duplicated() was the one I was looking for.